# SCCP and GSM MAP packets analysis with Java or C#

Tags: c#, java, packet, gsm

I have to analyze GSM MAP and SCCP packets. 
Wireshark decodes these packets without any problems, but I would need to do very similar task using Java or C#. The application will be written from the scratch. Sniffing packets is not a problem, however analyzing IP packets and getting SCCP/ GSM MAP data (such as “imsi” number) is very complicated.

Perhaps you have an idea how to handle it in a convenient way, without reading tons of documentation? Perhaps there is some open source software suitable for this task (ideally open source, Java or C# as primary language)?

Comment: Can you embed wireshark into your application? Are you a batch application or interactive?

Comment: Unfortunately it will be a batch application. It will run in background.

Answer (score 3):

Mobicents jSS7 stack is Open Source stack that can help you decode these packets https://code.google.com/p/jss7/

Comment: Can we use this library for sending SMS with E1 card?

Comment: Yes kodmanyagha you can use TelScale jSS7 (enterprise version of Mobicents) to send SMS over E1's

Answer (score 0):

SCCP is relatively easy to decode but you will have no other choice but to put your head into some specifications. For ITU you should be alright with the specification Q.713 and for ANSI, T1.112.3 (which is the SCCP Formats and Codes)

Now for the GSM MAP this is where the fun begins. I suggest that you get some readings on the abstract syntax notation one (ASN.1). The GSM MAP is all defined with this too flexible notation. Again you'll need to download from the [ITU](http://www.itu.int) website all the specs and ASN.1 for GSM MAP. Why the ASN.1 you say? Because you will find commercial compilers out there which will compile all the ASN.1 specifications into C, C++, Java or C#.

Take a look here: [Introduction to ASN.1](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm)